# Prove that these functions are continuous

Tags: limits

Prove that these functions are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \exp\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right), &x\neq0 \\ 
0, & x=0 \\
\end{cases}$$

$$
g(x)=\begin{cases} \exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right), & |x|<1 \\ 
0, & |x| \ge1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

For $f(x)$ would it be enough to prove that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \exp{(\frac{-1}{x^2})}=0$?

And for $g(x)$ would it be enough to prove that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -1} \exp{\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)}=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +1}\exp{\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)}=0$?

Comment: yes. you have right.

Answer (score 1):

For $f$ you are completely right. For $g$ it would be enough to show that *one sided* limits exist:

$$\lim_{x\to -1^+}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)=0$$

Because two sided limits don't exist.